# Redirect PATCH and PUT route rails 5 to use POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently adding proper routes into a legacy rails application, I can't seem to use PATCH, PUT and DELETE routes as the way the app works currently it only goes based on GET and POST routes.

So I've implemented REST routes but for the time being, I need to redirect PATCH, PUT and DELETE until such time we can change it to use proper routing.

Here's what I get while updating:

[image]

These are the routes for custom fields# custom_fields

```rb
resources :custom_fields, except: %i[show destroy] do
  get :disable, on: :member
  
  collection do
    get :list
    get :edit
    get :disable
    get :enable
    get :order_fields
    post :process_order_fields
  end
end
# remap wrong implmentation of paths
get '/custom_fields/edit/:id', to: redirect('/custom_fields/%{id}/edit')
```

[image]

I've tried the following

```rb
post '/custom_fields/:id', to: redirect(custom_field_path(id: %{id}))
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question. Why do you "need" to add these redirects?

If you wish to define a legacy `POST` route like `post '/custom_fields/:id'`, but internally have it perform the same action as the non-legacy `PUT/PATCH` request, then just define it as such:

```
resources :custom_fields, except: %i[show destroy] do
  post :update, on: :member
  # ...
end
```

Moreover, it is *invalid* to define this as a redirect as you attempted, [according to the HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Comment: Ah OK that works thanks, in regards to the way I'm doing the redirect this is following rails docs https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: A `GET --> GET` redirect is perfectly fine/normal according to the HTTP specification, and your approach would have been fine for that use case.